# How to get client models (based on Keras) in tensorflow federated?

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I am looking for a way to get client models as checkpoints that I can investigate as standard keras model. I looked into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58247978/tensorflow-federated-learning-checkpoint) but it only provides the weights, is there a way to get or save models from clients directly during federated training?

Answer (score 1):

The answer referenced in the original question provides a method for sending back the model weights; what seems to be missing is how to assign those weights to a `tf.keras.Model` that has the same architecture? With [`tff.learning.assign_weights_to_keras_model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/assign_weights_to_keras_model), a Keras model instance can be initialized with the clients weights, and the instance will provide the standard Keras API (`evaluate()`, `test_on_batch()` etc).

The [Federated Learning for Text Generation](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_text_generation) tutorial has an example of doing this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. To be clear, if I make changes in 'simple_fedavg.py', then I need to install the TFF from source?

Comment: Depends on the goal, simple_fedavg.py should be usable with the pip package, it only imports the top-level package. In other words, I would expect it to be possible to simply `import simple_fedavg` on a system that has tensorflow_federated pip package installed.


 Anything under the `research/` folder is considered experimental and not included in the pip package, but typically is usable with the pip package.

Comment: That's great! Thank you very much.

Comment: The code mentioned in referenced question (for processing client delta) is resulting in following error:


`TypeError: tf_computation's can accept only parameter types with constituents SequenceType, NamedTupleType and TensorType; you have attempted to create one with the type <conv2d/kernel=float32[3,3,1,32],conv2d/bias=float32[32],conv2d_1/kernel=float32[3,3,32,64],conv2d_1/bias=float32[64],dense/kernel=float32[36864,10],dense/bias=float32[10]>*@SERVER`

What could be the problem?

Comment: The issue is due to `type` mismatch. The `client_deltas` are of type `tensorflow_federated.python.core.impl.value_impl.ValueImpl`. Any ideas on how it can be fixed?

Comment: could you please look into this?

Comment: The error message is saying that `tff.tf_computation` decorated methods only accepts _unplaced_ values, but is being called with a value that is _placed_ at the `SERVER`. Probably [`tff.federated_map(function, value)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/federated_map) (which applies a `tff.tf_computation` decorated method called `function` to a _placed_ value) may help?

Comment: `client_deltas = tff.federated_collect(client_outputs.weights_delta)`
`@tff.tf_computation(client_deltas.type_signature)`
 `def check(deltas):`
      `print(deltas)`

`tff.federated_map(check, (client_deltas))`

I tried this based on your comment but error persists.